# GCC is always trying to use the static libc library instead of shared

Tags: unix, gcc, linker, centos

I'm not sure what went wrong on my server, it's running CentOS 7 and I recently tried to build a library and got the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

First, I thought it's a mistake in the libraries source code, but after some testing I created a minimal working C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout<<"works!";
}
```

And I try to build it first statically...

```
gcc -static main.c
```

Works. Generates `a.out`, which is what I expected, now if I type...

```
gcc main.c
```

I get the same error as above, it tries to link libc.a but I didnt specify static linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with:

`yum install glibc-devel.i686 glibc-i686`